# GROUP BY multiple different values together in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
+---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
|   cat   | pn | color | qty |   po    |
+---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
| marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-01 |
| marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-05 |
| marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-08 |
| marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-01 |
| marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-05 |
| marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-08 |
| marbles | 14 | white |  10 | 2019-01 |
| marbles | 14 | white |  10 | 2019-05 |
| marbles | 14 | white |  10 | 2019-08 |
| marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-01 |
| marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-05 |
| marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-08 |
+---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
```

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2008. I've got the above table. It is an inventory of marbles.

I want to get a sum of qty grouped by color, but I need the white and clear colors grouped together.

My query

```
SELECT SUM([qty]) AS [colorqty], [color]
FROM [inventory].[dbo].[marbles]
WHERE [qty] > 0
GROUP BY [color]
```

results

```
+----------+-------+
| colorqty | color |
+----------+-------+
|       30 | blue  |
|       30 | clear |
|       30 | red   |
|       30 | white |
+----------+-------+
```

I'd like to get the following result while both clear and white have quantity available. Clear is counted as white as long as white is available.

```
+----------+-------+
| colorqty | color |
+----------+-------+
|       30 | blue  |
|       60 | white |
|       30 | red   |
+----------+-------+
```

Once no more white available, I'd like the clear to be counted as clear again.

```
    +---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
    |   cat   | pn | color | qty |   po    |
    +---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
    | marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-01 |
    | marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-05 |
    | marbles | 12 | blue  |  10 | 2019-08 |
    | marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-01 |
    | marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-05 |
    | marbles | 13 | red   |  10 | 2019-08 |
    | marbles | 14 | white |   0 | 2019-01 |
    | marbles | 14 | white |   0 | 2019-05 |
    | marbles | 14 | white |   0 | 2019-08 |
    | marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-01 |
    | marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-05 |
    | marbles | 15 | clear |  10 | 2019-08 |
    +---------+----+-------+-----+---------+
```

Results in

```
    +----------+-------+
    | colorqty | color |
    +----------+-------+
    |       30 | blue  |
    |       30 | clear |
    |       30 | red   |
    +----------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `CASE` statement to select the colour `clear` as `white`?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is MS SQL server, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement in your `group by`, as long as the identical statement is in your `select`.

```
SELECT SUM([qty]) AS [colorqty], 
    case when [color] in ('white', 'clear')
       then 'white/clear' 
       else [color] end as [marblecolor] FROM [inventory].[dbo].[marbles] 
WHERE [qty] > 0 
GROUP BY 
    case when [color] in ('white', 'clear') 
       then 'white/clear' 
       else [color] end as [marblecolor]
```

Comment: I wrote this on SQL server, but I obviously don't have your database.  What error are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to sum the quantity, and display the max color when grouped by color except that color clear should be treated as color white when grouping:

```
select sum(qty) qty
     , max(color) color
  from marbles
 group by case color
            when 'clear' then 'white'
            else color
          end
```